# Is there a difference in space complexities for array of numbers/strings and array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there a difference in the space complexity for an average 1D array (like: ar = [1, 2, 3 .... n]) and array of objects (like: ar = [{name: 'A', id: 1}, ..... {name: ''AN", id: N}]? Also if there are more attributes in each object in the object array, how that will effect the space complexity?

Comment: Deeply nested structures do not inherently represent any increase in memory and computational iterations over a flat array of the same size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The only affect that arrays have on javascript storage engines are memory consumptions. Objects, strings, boolean values, all are just a `length` under the hood represented by bytes. So a string of the same length as an object with nested values will not have any additional affect on storage. Computationally speaking, accessing a deeply nested object at an exact location, e.g. `myArray[0].titles['tree][0]` does not have any performance implications over `myArray[0]`. The access to the location within the tree **will** be more costly when traversing over the array and its children, though.

Answer (score 2):

If the objects represent constant space, then the space *complexity* does not change. There is only a different coefficient:

For instance, an array of *n* numbers occupies *a* + *bn* space, where *a* is the array overhead:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If the array has objects with numbers instead, for instance:

```
 [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}, {x: 4}]
```

...then again the occupied space is *a* + *cn*, where *c* is a constant that is greater than the previously mentioned *b*. But that is still the same space *complexity*, i.e. it is linear in terms of the length of the array.

This remains true if the objects happen to have 5 properties instead of 1, ... In your example there is one reservation though: strings can have arbitrary lengths, so if you have string properties (or bigint properties, or nested arrays) then either you must agree that there is a fixed maximum length for those, or take that dimension as a second variable in the determination of the space complexity.

Comment: Nitpick: fixed maximum *average* length. If half of the nested elements have length 1, a quarter of them has length 2, an eighth of them has length 4 etc, the space complexity of the whole array is still linear even if large arrays might contain a few very long elements.